# How to generate serial key for .exe file in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, exe

I am creating the .exe file through WPF. I want to generate serial key for that .exe file and I give the rights for the serial key will apply for only 3 system. If may install the 4th one then it says, "the key is not valid" message. How to do.

Comment: This isn't a simple task that we can just give you a code snippet for mate. You'll have to do it on your own.

Comment: `CurrentKey ++` will give you decent serial keys... :) But "how to implement licensing for my application" is way too broad for SO.

Answer (score 0):

Three suggestions I would recommend looking at

1) Assuming you have a website, write a callback routine to to your website to validate a custom generated serial number, or something simpler like a use count.

2) Do it through InstallShield. There is a good 15 minute video explaining how to do set up serial number access. There is also a 4 minute part 2, for an additional way as well.

3) create a dll. For an example, see the source code at: http://support.installshield.com/kb/files/Q104870/Serial.c

Any of these suggestions may get you close to what you are looking for.